# my jsp not allowing expression lanugage

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, model-view-controller

> HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl

---

type Exception report

```
message java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:348)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:236)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:257)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1183)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:902)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.prepareExpression(Validator.java:1618)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:748)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$ELExpression.accept(Node.java:968)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2392)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2444)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2450)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:474)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2392)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1845)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:218)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:236)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:257)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1183)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:902)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.57 logs.

Comment: i used isELIgnored=false and when using ${status.value} or ${status.errorMessages} then getting exception

Comment: If this is a Maven project can you post your POM? You should actually be doing the exact opposite of what was suggested below and ensuring you are *not* including JARs in web-INF/lib that should be provided by the container.

Comment: `isELIgnored="false"` is for `${...}`. `deferredSyntaxAllowedAsLiteral="false"` for `#{...}`. Though both flags are more or less default, if not otherwise globally configured.